# window.location,hash gives problem when clicking the browser back button in React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am working on someone else written code.

We are loading content from the database depending on the scroll of the user. When the user scrolls the data keeps loading until all data is retrieved from the DB. The client wants to see the section number in which Data is being loaded.

To show the number in the URL, the previous developer has used `window.location.hash()` but because of this, we are not able to take the user to the previous page when they click on the back button. Instead, it keeps on jumping on the page for few times and then goes back.

I cannot understand what else do i need to do to fix it. Below is the code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ComponentView from './view';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
import { createAction,ActionNames } from '../../redux/actions/index';
/**
 * @name Product Grid Component
 * @type Component
 * @author Inderdeep Singh
 */
class Main extends Component {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param props
     */
    state = {
        items: [],
        isLoading: true,
        cursor: 0
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.pageSize = 10;
        this.state = {
            data:[],
            link:'',
            loading:true,
            items: [],
            isLoading: false,
            loadAll:false,
            cursor: 0,
            arrSize: 12,
            productsLen:0,
            section:0,
            scrollUp:0,
            url:'',
            sectionSize:'',
            sectionSizeLim:1
        }
        // if(props.query){
        //  this.getProducts();
        // }
        this.handleOnScroll = this.handleOnScroll.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {

        // this.loadMore()
        // console.log(this.props);


    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);

    }


    /**
     * Component Did Mount
     */
    componentDidMount(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        this.setState({url:url})
            if(url.indexOf('#')>-1){
                if(url.indexOf('kategori')>-1){
                    url = url.split('/');
                    var pageNum = url[6];
                    var catName = url[4];
                    var timesRun = 0;
                    var Scrolling = setInterval(function () {
                        timesRun += 1;
                        if(timesRun <= pageNum){
                            window.scrollTo(0, pageNum * 1930);
                            var fact ='/kategori/'+catName+'/#/page/'+timesRun;
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;

                            // history.pushState(null,null,fact);
                        }
                        else{
                            clearInterval(Scrolling)
                        }
                    },1000);
                }
                else if(url.indexOf('produkt')>-1){
                    url = url.split('/');
                    var pageNum = url[6];
                    var catName = url[4];
                    var timesRun = 0;
                    var Scrolling = setInterval(function () {
                        timesRun += 1;
                        if(timesRun <= pageNum){
                            window.scrollTo(0, pageNum * 1930);
                            var fact ='/produkt/'+catName+'/#/page/'+timesRun;
                            window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
                            // history.pushState(null,null,fact);
                        }
                        else{
                            clearInterval(Scrolling)
                        }
                    },1000);
                }
                else{
                    url = url.split('#');
                    url = url[1].split('/');
                    url = url[2];
                    var timesRun = 0;
                    var Scrolling = setInterval(function () {
                        timesRun += 1;
                        if(timesRun <= url){
                            window.scrollTo(0, url * 1930);
                            // history.pushState(null,null,'/#/page/'+timesRun);
                            window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
                        }
                        else{
                            clearInterval(Scrolling)
                        }
                    },1000);

                }

                }

        const {emitter} = this.props;
        emitter.addListener("REFRESH_PRODUCTS",(query)=>{               
            this.getProducts(1,query)
        })
        this.setState({data:this.props.data})
        // this.loadMore()
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleOnScroll);
        this.doQuery();
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if(JSON.stringify(this.props.query)!=JSON.stringify(newProps.query)){
            this.getProducts(1,newProps.query)
        }
        // console.log(this.state.arrSize);

    }
    // scrollIt=() => { window.scrollTo(0, 1000)}
    doQuery = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, error: undefined })
        axios.post('/getProducts')
            .then((res) => {
                // console.log(parseInt(res.data.results.length/12))
                this.setState({
                    // items: [...state.items, ...res.items],
                    // cursor: res.cursor,
                    // isLoading: false
                    // newData: this.state.newData.slice().concat(res.data)
                    // newData: this.state.olddata.concat(res.data.results)
                    productsLen:res.data.results.length,
                    sectionSize:parseInt(res.data.results.length/12)
                });
            })
    }
    handleOnScroll() {
        var self = this;
function callURL(ss){
    // var self = this;
    var url = window.location.href;
        setTimeout(
            self.setState({
                arrSize: self.state.arrSize + 12,
                isLoading: true
            }), 3000);
        var url = window.location.href;
        if(self.state.sectionSizeLim<=self.state.sectionSize){
            self.setState({
                sectionSizeLim: self.state.sectionSizeLim + 1,
            })
        }
        if (self.state.arrSize <= self.props.product_list.length) {
            var sect = self.state.section;
            if (url.indexOf('#') > -1) {
                url = url.split('#');
                url = url[1].split('/');
                url = url[2];
                if (sect <= url) {
                    sect = sect + 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                sect = sect + 1;
            }
            self.setState({
                isLoading: true,
                section: sect
            })
        }
        else {
            self.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                loadAll: true
            })
        }
        if(ss==0){
            if (self.state.url.indexOf('kategori') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/kategori/' + url[4] ;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
                // window.location.hash = '';
                // window.location.href.split('#')[0];
                // window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", fact,"/");
            }
            else if (self.state.url.indexOf('produkt') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/produkt/' + url[4] ;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
                // window.location.hash = '';
                // window.location.href.split('#')[0];
                // window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", fact,"/");
            }
            else {
                // history.pushState(null, null, '/');
                var fact = '/' + ss ;
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
                // window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/");
            }   
        }
        else{
            if (self.state.url.indexOf('kategori') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/kategori/' + url[4] + '/page/' + ss;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                // window.location.hash = fact;
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
            }
            else if (self.state.url.indexOf('produkt') > -1) {
                var url = self.state.url.split('/');
                var fact = '/produkt/' + url[4] + '/page/' + ss;
                // history.pushState(null, null, fact);
                // window.location.hash = fact;
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
            }
            else {
                // history.pushState(null, null, '/#/page/' + ss);
                window.location.hash = "/"+ss;
            }
        }
}
        var h = ($("html").scrollTop());
        if(h == 0 ){
            callURL(0);
        }
        else if(h >= 0 && h <= 1930){
            callURL(0); 
        }
        else if (h >= 1930 && h <= 3860) {
            callURL(1)
        }
        else if (h >= 3860 && h <= 5790) {
            callURL(2)
        }
        else if (h >= 5790 && h <= 7720) {
            callURL(3)
        }
        else if (h >= 7720 && h <= 9650) {
            callURL(4)
        }
        else if (h >= 9650 && h <= 11580) {
            callURL(5)
        }
        else if (h >= 11580 && h <= 13510) {
            callURL(6)
        }
        else if (h >= 13510 && h <= 15440) {
            callURL(7)
        }
        else if (h >= 15440 && h <= 17370) {
            callURL(8)
        }
        else if (h >= 17370 && h <= 19300) {
            callURL(9)
        }
        else if (h >= 19300 && h <= 21230) {
            callURL(10)
        }
        else if (h >= 21230 && h <= 23160) {
            callURL(11)
        }
        else if (h >= 23160 && h <= 25090) {
            callURL(12)
        }
        else if (h >= 25090 && h <= 27020) {
            callURL(13)
        }
        else if (h >= 27020 && h <= 28950) {
            callURL(14)
        }
        else if (h >= 28950 && h <= 30880) {
            callURL(15)
        }
        else if (h >= 30880 && h <= 32810) {
            callURL(16)
        }
        else if (h >= 32810 && h <= 34740) {
            callURL(17)
        }
        else if (h >= 34740 && h <= 36670) {
            callURL(18)
        }
        else if (h >= 36670 && h <= 38600) {
            callURL(19)
        }
        else if (h >= 38600 && h <= 40530) {
            callURL(20)
        }
        else if (h >= 40530 && h <= 42460) {
            callURL(21)
        }
        else if (h >= 42460 && h <= 44390) {
            callURL(22)
        }
        else if (h >= 44390 && h <= 46320) {
            callURL(23)
        }
        else if (h >= 46320 && h <= 48250) {
            callURL(24)
        }
        else if (h >= 48250 && h <= 50180) {
            callURL(25)
        }
        else if (h >= 50180 && h <= 52110) {
            callURL(26)
        }
        else if (h >= 52110 && h <= 54040) {
            callURL(27)
        }
        else if (h >= 54040 && h <= 55970) {
            callURL(28)
        }
        else if (h >= 55970 && h <= 57900) {
            callURL(29)
        }
        else if (h >= 57900 && h <= 59830) {
            callURL(30)
        }
        else if (h >= 59830 && h <= 61760) {
            callURL(31)
        }
        else{
        console.log(h);
        }


        var scrollTop = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
        var scrollHeight = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
        var scrollHeights = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
        scrollHeight = scrollHeight - 1000;
        var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;
        var scrolledToBottom = Math.ceil(scrollTop + clientHeight) >= scrollHeight;
        var scrollToTop = Math.ceil(scrollTop - clientHeight) >= scrollHeight;

    }
    /**
     * Get products
     * @param page
     */
    getProducts(page,customQuery){
        page = page || 1;
        // console.log(page);
        const {getProducts,query} = this.props;
        let obj = {
            ...query,
            ...customQuery,
            query : {
                ...(query || {}).query,
                ...(customQuery || {}).query
            },
            // limit : this.pageSize,
            limit : 5000,
            // skip : (page-1)*this.pageSize
            skip : 0
        };
        obj.query = {
            ...obj.query,
            state : 'published'
        }
        getProducts(obj).then(action=>{
            // // if(page>1){
            //  document.getElementById('product-grid').scrollIntoView();   
            // // }

        })
    }

    /**
     * Render the view
     * @returns {*}
     */
    render() {
        return (ComponentView.bind(this))();
    }
}

/**
 * Bind Actions
 * @param dispatch
 * @returns Object
 */
function bindAction(dispatch) {
    return {
        getProducts : (data)=>{
            return dispatch(createAction(ActionNames.GET_PRODUCTS,data));
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Map the shared state to properties
 * @param state
 * @returns Object
 */
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    // console.log(state)
    return {
        data: state.products.results || [],
        count : state.products.count,
        hasMore : state.products.hasMore,
        emitter : state.emitter
    };
};

//Set display name to be used in React Dev Tools
Main.displayName = 'Product Grid';

export default connect(mapStateToProps,bindAction)(Main);
```

This is the site on which we are getting the problem. https://www.tagminepenge.dk/

Go on some page and scroll down then try to click on the back button of the browser. You will understand the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every time you call window.location a new url is pushed in the browser history stack. To solve it use **history.replace** provided by the react router it will replace the current url in the history stack so when you go back want make the same problem.
[history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Logout extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
}

Logout = () => {
    this.props.history.replace('/');
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Your Links</h1>
            <button onClick={this.Logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am kinda new with react router. Can you please write down an example code for me like where I need to place that code.

Comment: Replace window.location.hash with this.props.history.replace().